# Omnipay Mollie implementation

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm working on a webshop that should have an integration with Mollie to provide the payment methods. Craft Commerce's docs mention that Mollie is already integrated by using the Omnipay interface.

Am I correct that Omnipay only provides a basic interface to communicate with various Payment Gateways (including Mollie) and does not include more concrete functionality, like getting the payment methods/issuing banks?

Basically, the code like below I still have to write myself? Or am I doing double work?

```
public function actionGetPaymentMethods()
{
    $this->requireAjaxRequest();

    $paymentResponse = $this->gateway->fetchPaymentMethods()->send();

    if ($paymentResponse->isSuccessful()) {
        $paymentMethods = array();
        foreach ($paymentResponse->getPaymentMethods() as $paymentMethod) {
            $paymentMethods[] = array(
                'id' => $paymentMethod->getId(),
                'name' => $paymentMethod->getName(),
            );
        }

        $this->returnJson($paymentMethods);
    }

    $this->returnErrorJson('error');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I did not understand that Mollie is an off-site implementation. So the checkout just redirects you to the Mollie environment. If you want to implement on-site payments using Mollie you'd have to write your own logic I presume.